# How to print out the quantity of numbers in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello guys a part of a school exercise is to print out the `.length` of numbers in my textarea. In other words also if there are strings in the textarea it should only count the numbers.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <p class="ptags">Kommentar:</p>
    <textarea id="kommentar" rows="5"></textarea>
    <p>Kommentar Ziffern</p>
    <p id="ikomm"></p>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
/*Anzahl Ziffern in der Kommentarbox*/
function zkommentar(){
    var zkomm = document.getElementById('kommentar').value.length;
    var numbers = zkomm.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
    var string = parseInt(numbers);
    document.getElementById('ikomm').innerHTML = numbers;
}
/*Ausgabe*/
function Ausgabe() {
    {
        document.getElementById('Ausgabe').innerHTML =
            namelength();
            kommentar();
            uhrzeit();
            datum();
            bdata();
            quadrat();
            quersumme();
            zkommentar();
    }
};
```

Comment: Here is working sample for you: https://jsfiddle.net/pw9ehkf6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing many things here.

First, you should only store the `value` of `#kommentar`, not it's length.

Then, after applying your RegEx, the amount of numbers in your textarea will be the `length` of your `numbers` variable :

```js
function zkommentar() {
  var zkomm = document.getElementById('kommentar').value;
  var numbers = zkomm.match(/\d/g).map(Number);
  var string = numbers.length;
  document.getElementById('ikomm').innerHTML = string;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p class="ptags">Kommentar:</p>
  <textarea id="kommentar" rows="5"></textarea>
  <p>Kommentar Ziffern</p>
  <p id="ikomm"></p>
</form>

<button onclick="zkommentar();">Test</button>
```

Comment: And why do I not need parseInt?. I thought that everything in the textarea is a string and if you want to make it a number you use ParseInt. Isen't that right.

Comment: @Sandro21  You're only checking the length of an array, which always returns an integer.

Comment: Okey intersting.:) Your answer still dosen't work though. It always returns 1.

Comment: @Sandro21 It works. It will tell you how many numbers (can be > 10) are inside your textarea. IF you want to get the number of individual numbers, just use `/\d/g` instead of `/\d+/g`

Answer (score 0):

To get the length of the numbers, you could use `\d` for the regex, which will match all the digits instead of `\d+` which will match one or more digits.

[Match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) can return `null`, so you first should check for it:

```
var zkomm = document.getElementById('kommentar').value;
var numbers = zkomm.match(/\d/g)
if (numbers) {
    numbers = numbers.map(Number);
    var string = numbers.length;
    document.getElementById('ikomm').innerHTML = string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers do not care about real numbers

For example "1s" is not a number

```js
function zkommentar() {
  var zkomm = document.getElementById('kommentar').value;
  var numbers = zkomm.split(' ').filter(_isNumber);
  var string = numbers.length;
  document.getElementById('ikomm').innerHTML = string;
}

function _isNumber(value) {
    return Number.isFinite(+value)
        ? value
        : null;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p class="ptags">Kommentar:</p>
  <textarea id="kommentar" rows="5"></textarea>
  <p>Kommentar Ziffern</p>
  <p id="ikomm"></p>
</form>

<button onclick="zkommentar();">Test</button>
```